# Prove there exists a basis with respect to which the tranformation matrix is...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem:**

Suppose that $S : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear transformation such that $S^2=S$, $S\ne 0$ and $S\ne I$. Prove there is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to which the matrix $A_S$ of $S$ is $$A_S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

**Working:**

I know that the matrix of $S$ with respect to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ must be similar to $A_S$. However, in class I recall my instructor saying that $\{Sv,v\}$ for all $0\ne v\in \mathbb{R}^2$ was such a basis.

Let $\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, we have $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ 
However, $$S(xSv + yv)=xS^2v+ySv=xSv+ySv=(x+y)Sv.$$
Is $\{Sv,v\}$ an example of such a basis? If it is, why? If it is not, what is an example?

Comment: $\{v,Sv\}$ is not a basis in general, even if $v\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S^2-S=S(S-I)=0.$$
Therefore, the minimal polinomial of $S$ is one of the following.

1. $m_S(x)=x$.
2. $m_S(x)=x-1$
3. $m_S(x)=x(x-1).$

Since $S\neq 0,I$, we got $m_S(x)=x(x-1),$
and from here the result follows.

Comment: So, an example of a basis would be $\{v,w\}$ such that $Sv=v$, $Sw=0$ and $v,w\ne 0$?

Comment: @eloiPrime Yes.